# How to tone an image to with a specific color? Like greyscale, but toned

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, adobe-fireworks

I need this image in a grayscale `rgb(82, 82, 74)`, hex: `#52524A`:

[image]

How can I do this on Fireworks or Photoshop?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Is this what your referencing? the `#52524A` color as the top most of grayscale.
this was achieved via `image > adjustments > gradient map`. and setting the black to `#52524A`.

Answer (score 3):

To make the entire image grayscale: `image` -> `adjustment` -> `black and white`

[image]

First, understand that greyscale is a scale of bright-to-dark values that have nothing to do with color. Two very different colors can appear very similar or identical if you simply desaturate the image, because only the color, not the tonal ("grey") value, was providing the contrast.

Here is an example of a color image that clearly shows contrasting colors:

[image: Different colors, same tone]

Watch what happens if we simple desaturate the image, apply a simple gradient map or change the layer's Blend Mode to Luminosity with a black, grey or white layer below:

[image: Desaturated image]

Wait, what? Where did the rectangles go? Although we perceive the *colors* as different, they have exactly the same greyscale *tonal value* -- something of vital interest when you want to convert them to greyscale.

Photoshop's Black and White adjustment layer at its default setting does a slightly better job, but not much:

[image: Deafult BW conversion]

That's not a big improvement, but if we adjust the color sliders a little, we get a result that is a much *better representation of how the original looks*:

[image: Adjust BW settings give a better result]

So you're best to use this approach, then add the one additional step that will give you the color value you want.

- Add a Black and White adjustment layer.
- Use the sliders to adjust the greyscale brightness of different colors in the image until you have matched the appearance of the original as closely as possible.
- Then click the "Tint" checkbox (lower left on Mac, like boblet's image, upper left in Windows), set the color to `#52524A` and you're done.

You now have your greyscale image based on that exact color, and only that color. How you can verify that is a matter for another day. It's not hard, but it takes a while to explain.

Comment: But i want a scale like this shade of grey #52524A

Comment: The confusion comes in when the OP says he wants a "greyscale" (which by definition has no color information) with a fixed RGB value (which is like saying you want a ladder that has only one rung, because brightness is part of the RGB information). I think it's a language issue, or lack of terminology.

Comment: I took your suggestion, but added my expanded answer to this one rather than the other way round. As you observed, it keeps things all in one place. :-)

Comment: That was both practical and very nice of you :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't *actually* sound like you want greyscale. You want a toned image.

In Photoshop....

- `Image > Adjustments > Desaturate`
- Add a new layer above and fill it with `#52524A`
- Set `#52524A` layer Blend Mode to **color**
- Add a mask to allow the color to only cover the image area (and leave transparent areas transparent.)

[image]

You can do the same exact thing by adding a **Color Overlay Layer Style** set to *color*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: add a Hue/Saturation layer and turn down the saturation slider. Select colorize and adjust the hue to choose your color.

Answer (score 0):

also, there's

`Image > Mode > Duotone`: setting one to your color choosen, and one to white or grey

there are a multitude of ways to do what you're asking.